# libopkele example openid

Tags: c++, openid

is there any documentation or guide or example to `libopkele` ? I've run doxygen on its source But its hard to figure out how to use it.
Till now I've only figured out `libopkele::idiscover()` and `libopkele::yadiscover()` and there is an `association` class that acts a a container of association response. There is `libopkele::basic_OP` which I need to extend and implement pure virtuals 

Were can I get a Guide to libopkele ? or I am making some mistake in generating/reading dox or Is it a pretty simple thing that I am messing up ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `test` directory in which you can find an example RP and OP implementations. You don't have to satisfy the dependencies and compile them, just read.

Comment: Relying Party and Openid Provider. You can't really go for OpenID development without getting acquainted with specs and terminology.